# How do debug ng-click doesn't work in modal?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have this button in my modal footer :

```
<button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="run()">Create</button>
```

---

**app.js**

```
"use strict";

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], function($interpolateProvider,$httpProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');

    //Setting headers
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = "XMLHttpRequest";
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content');

});

myApp.controller('skillController', function skillController($scope,$log,$http) {

    $scope.run = function() {
        console.log('RUNNN ----- ');
    };

});
```

---

**HTML**

I have

```
<div class="row" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="skillController" >

...

</div>
```

I couldn't get this

```
console.log('RUNNN ----- ');
```

to run on my console.

What should I look into?

Comment: do you see any errors in console? also have you refered the js file?

Comment: console perfectly clean ....

Comment: I triple check the syntax in my `app.js` my HTML and everywhere. Could it be another `create()` function declare.

Comment: i dont see any problem with the code, probably you can create a plunker and add here

Comment: Good Idea. I will try to do that.

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/pkjuee24lMTgmhZx938c/

Comment: I couldn't get my alert to display. I have no idea what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are not passing $scope to your controller,

```
myApp.controller('skillController', function skillController($scope) {
    $scope.run = function($scope) {
        alert('RUNNN ----- ');
   };

});
```

**DEMO**

```js
"use strict";

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], function() {});

myApp.controller('skillController', function skillController($scope) {
    $scope.run = function($scope) {
        alert('RUNNN ----- ');
   };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="skillController" >
    <button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="run()">Create</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: function($scope) <----- this scope define by never use.

Comment: @ihue i dont get it

Comment: `myApp.controller('skillController', function skillController($scope) {
    $scope.run = function($scope) {
        alert('RUNNN ----- ');
   };

});`

Comment: Your `$scope` declared in `function($scope)` <----- this `$scope` define but never use.

Comment: I still have issue with my app even if your answer to alert it and working. I still not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: Does it matter because my button in the modal ??

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea of the function in the module `function($interpolateProvider,$httpProvider)`, but if you delete this function, it will work well.
I know `angular.module('moduleName',[])` is used to create a new module, and `angular.module('moduleName')` is to use an existing module.
Can `module()` method can have the third param?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15464641)

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake. Thank you for your suggestion.